# JavaScript: Access class from MutationObserver

Tags: javascript

Given the following class:

```
function MyCustomClass(e){

    this.element = e;

    this.start(){

        var observer = new MutationObserver(this.mutationObserved),
        config = {
                attributes: true
        };
        observer.observe(this.element, config);

    }

    this.anotherFunction = function(){
        console.log("Another function was called");
    }

    this.mutationObserved = function(e){
        // This doesn't work
        this.anotherFunction();
    }
}
```

How do I access the class in which the `mutationObserved` class operates?

`this.anotherFunction` doesn't work because the scope is now within the `MutationObserver` class.

Comment: [`Function.prototype.bind`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind)

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
//...
var self = this;
this.mutationObserved = function(e){
  self.anotherFunction();
}
```

You need to capture the context for the outer function and then use it in the inner one.